# Update System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.0.2 to 5.4 Token Issues

Tags: c#, jwt

I am trying to update my code from `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` 4.0.2 to the latest version 5.4 but i got a couple errors that i can not figure it out.

```
app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
        new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataEndpoint = "MetadataEndpoint",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudience = "Audience",
                ValidIssuer = "Issuer"
            }
        }
```

`TokenValidationParameters` are not valid anymore.

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                }
            });
```

`IssuerSecurityTokenProviders` not available too.

Has any one encounter the same issue? any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be running into [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3017#issuecomment-280903273) issue?

> 5.x is not compatible with Katana 3 - it is for .NET Core going forward. You need to stay on 4.x

Comment: I do not think is the same issue since we are note using Katana 3. But they have a similar problem as we do right now. The other thing it might solve my problem is to find a way to Decript the a token using the secret key on System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.0.2, the code i used in other projects is not supported on version 5